# An SVG image is clipped a little

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am working with the SVG format and I have some issue with "clipping". It's meaning that I have wight\height and the viewbox property (that the same like width and height) but it's rendering not correct somehow.

[image]

My svg code

```
<svg width="520" height="484" viewBox="0 0 520 484" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMin meet" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="vs-figure">
```

in my css I have an responsive rule

```
.vs-figure
  max-width: 520px
  width: 100%
  height: 100%
```

Why it is rendering like that? My other svg are rendering normally but this one isn't.

I saw that to have the responsive behaviour I should use the viewbox and css  width/height 100%

Actually I can resolve this issue via setting:     `overflow: visible`  to my SVG but I don't know if it is right.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Presumably the contents of the SVG (which you haven't showed us the markup for) extend outside the viewBox.

Comment: Hi Robert. Sorry, I didn't show it because it is so big peace of code and I didn't sure that it can be useful to answer.
Actually is it possible that content of svg can be bigger than viewBox? I thought it's like content inside container and it's can't be bigger (like in normal case of HTML)

Comment: Sure it's possible. The viewBox defines what's visible, you're free to draw outside that if you want.

Comment: I didn't know that. Actually the issue was in this point. I changed the viewBox prop and it helps me to fix that issue. Thank you Robert